# How do I make ack ignore a file in a directory?

Tags: bash, pattern-matching, ack

I have a file in a directory `a/b/c.js`

I can't ignore `c.js` with `--ignore-file=match:c.js` because I want to match other file named `c.js`

I can't ignore dir `a/b` with `--ignore-dir=a/b` because **there are other files I care about in `a/b`**

I've tried:

```
--ignore-file=a/b/c.js       "Invalid filter specification"
```

I've tried:

```
--ignore-file=match:/a\/b\/c.js/
```

Doesn't work, and I'm guessing that it's because ack doesn't read the file path as part of the match, just the name.

I've tried:

```
--ignore-dir=match:/a\/b\/c.js/     " Non-is filters are not yet supported for --ignore-dir (what?)"
```

I can't find anything useful in the [Ack manual](http://beyondgrep.com/documentation/ack-2.12-man.html) soup. How do I ignore a file in a directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is [it is impossible](https://github.com/petdance/ack2/issues/479).

Answer (score 1):

You might use `find ... ! -path ...` to easely search for files *not* matching a given path.

Further, `find ... -exec ... \{} \+` allows to launch a command with the list of files found appended.

I don't have `ack` at hand, but using `grep` as a place-holder, this will lead to:

```
sh$ echo toto > a/b/c.js
sh$ echo toto > a/c.js
sh$ echo toto > a/b/x.js
sh$ find . \! -path './a/b/c.js' -type f -exec grep toto \{} \+
#        ^           ^                         ^^^^
#      pattern should match              replace by a call to `ack`
#       your search path
./a/c.js:toto
./a/b/x.js:toto
```

---

EDIT: there is a potential pitfall with the `./` at the start of the *path pattern*.
you might prefer using `find ... ! -samefile ...` to reject found files having the same *inode* as the given file:

```
sh$ find . \! -samefile a/b/c.js -type f -exec grep toto \{} \+
#                      ^^^^^^^^
#                  no dot here; this is a *file*
#                  can't use glob patterns (*, ?, ...)
./a/c.js:toto
./a/b/x.js:toto
```

---

From `man find`:

> ```
>    ! expr True  if  expr  is false.  This character will also usually need
>           protection from interpretation by the shell.
>
>    -path pattern
>           File  name matches shell pattern pattern.  The metacharacters do
>           not treat `/' or `.' specially; so, for example,
>                     find . -path "./sr*sc"
>           [...]
>
>    -samefile name
>           File refers to the same inode as name.   When -L is  in  effect,
>           this can include symbolic links.
> ```